# Mysql error in Jira "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,I MPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='"

Tags: mysql, jira

I am trying to setup jira and I am using mysql database. I keep receiving this error all the time:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,I                                                                              MPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

What could cause this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the JIRA Setup guide. It's pretty obvious that you are using the wrong collation. JIRA uses `utf8_bin` as a collation. I would recommend you to take a look at this [document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/connecting-jira-applications-to-mysql-861253043.html) and follow the steps.

Comment: Thank you! I did yesterday and deleted the database, recreated it again and started from the beginning. It was quite clear that the collation was not set correctly.